# Android Keystore vs signing file?

Tags: android, sha1

I have been signing my apks with keys (files) I previously created using eclipse, these do not have file extenstions like ".keystore". I see in Android Studio, that for firebase, I now need to get the SHA1 in the keystore for release version. I have noticed that the cmd line command is not recognising the keys without the keystore extension from eclipse, perhaps because they don't have the keystore file extention? I have been using the "signingReport" but it generates based on the debug.keystore. The release version is always:
Variant: release
Config: none

What is the solution, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you can use keytool to verify if the key you have is valid and if you can verify that the key was valid then you can rename it with .keystore. However I don't have any problem with that on my Macbook, I even have ".jks" as my keystore extension and Android Studio recognize it just find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually adding .keystore to the end of the file seemed to solve the issue with it not being recognised by keytool